# C# app not running beyond initialisation

Tags: c#, winforms

**Program.cs**

```
namespace PerformanceMonitor
{
    static class Program
    {
        private static int NumberOfCores;
        private static List<int> CPULoadVals;

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MonitorGUI());

            NumberOfCores = getNumberOfCores();
            CPULoadVals = getCoreLoadVals();
        }

        private static int getNumberOfCores()
        {
            int coreCount = 0;
            foreach (var core in new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor").Get())
            {
                coreCount += int.Parse(core["NumberOfCores"].ToString());
            }
            return coreCount;
        }
        ...
```

**MonitorGUI.cs**

```
namespace PerformanceMonitor
{
    public partial class MonitorGUI : Form
    {
        public static List<Label> labels;
        private static List<int> CPULoadVals;

        public MonitorGUI()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ...
        }
```

Debugging the app I can see that `InitializeComponent()` is invoked causing a new form to be created (`Application.Run(new MonitorGUI());`)  but trying to step through after that and nothing is called. The method on form load is not even called even though I can visually see that it's loaded

Comment: Are you assigning to either of the lists in the `Load` event? Have they been initialized?

Comment: Did you wire any Load event like this this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);?

Comment: Neither List has been initialised and I have not wired any events

Comment: then you should. The Form1_load event is either generated by double clicking the load event property in Form window or you can manually wire up the load event.

Comment: Ah yes!! That did not help solve this problem but has helped me realise that I need to do that to prevent future ones, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Application.Run()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157902%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Begins running a standard application message loop on the current thread, and makes the specified form visible.

This method *blocks* and only returns when you close the `Form` passed as argument. So all calls after that are executed when you *close your main window*.

You might want to change the order:

```
 [STAThread]
 static void Main()
 {
     NumberOfCores = getNumberOfCores();
     CPULoadVals = getCoreLoadVals();

     Application.EnableVisualStyles();
     Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
     Application.Run(new MonitorGUI());
 }
```

---

And `Form1_Load()` is only called if you subscribed to the `Load` event of the `Form`:

```
public MonitorGUI()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Load += Form1_Load; // <--- subscribe to the event
}
```

But this can also be done in designer. Check if you have set this event correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much!! This has done the trick. Will accept when I can :)